# How to name or number code-block in reStructuredText and Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

I would line to auto number code-blocks in reStructuredText, if auto numbering is not possible then name/number them manually.

```
.. code-block:: python
    :name: super awesome code exaple no 5
    a = 1
```

When in training we can then reference them and tell students on witch example we now work on. We don't need to reference them in the document itself.

Is it possible in any way? Out of box or by extending Sphinx?

Comment: The https://github.com/jterrace/sphinxtr project includes an extension for numbered figures. Maybe you can use it as an inspiration if you want to create an extension for numbered code-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do that via extending Sphinx.

You have to create your own extension (see [how to create an extension](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/index.html#developing-extensions-for-sphinx) and [where to put your own extension](http://sphinx-doc.org/extensions.html#where-to-put-your-own-extensions)) which will implement you new custom directive (see [how to create a directive](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/markupapi.html#directives)).

Directives are usual Python classes, so your NamedCodeBlock directive class should extend the CodeBlock directive class (see `sphinx.directives.code.CodeBlock`) and add support for the `name` optional argument where you will be able to set names for your code blocks.